# SQL Developer spool command outputs commands as well as results

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, spool

I have an sql plus script that uses the SPOOL command to generate a file. I execute it with SQL Developer. When I execute the script, the spool file that is generated only includes the result of the select statement. And that is what I want. But the issue is that when an other user executes the script, it also includes the select-statement itself.

Script:

```
set pages 0
set lines 32000
set trimspool on
set feedback off
set echo off
set verify off
define vspoolfile = '''c:\temp\spoolfile.txt'''
spool &vspoolfile
select description from query; 
spool off
```

Result in spoolfile.txt:

```
> select description from query
Te behandelen
Te plannen
```

I do not want the first line with '> select description from query' in this file.
Because the script behaves differently on the other user's machine than on my machine, I think this is maybe a setting in SQL Developer somewhere? Can I force it to not include the statement itself?

Comment: I tried your script; nothing (but data) in my output file. How did you execute it? I wrote `@c:\temp\test.sql` into SQL Developer's Worksheet and ran it with Ctrl+Enter.

Answer (score 0):

Add
set term off
as well.  then, save those commands into a file and run it with the @ command from SQLPlus:

@c:\sqlcmd.sql

Answer (score 0):

"`set term off`" only applies to @ script invocations. For directly entered SQL commands, to hide the command itself from the spool file, invoke `sqlplus` with the `-S` option. You can also remove the column header with "`set heading off`".

```
sqlplus -S user/pass
set heading off
spool test.dat
select * from dual
/
spool off
exit
```

Comment: Right; but, Raf runs that code in **SQL Developer**, not SQL*Plus.

Comment: Sorry, I think the verbage "I have an sql plus script that uses the SPOOL command to generate a file" mislead me. Sure sounds like sql plus, even said sql plus. I guess I didn't see the contradictory mention of SQL Developer elsewhere.

Comment: Never mind, Paul. If I were you, I wouldn't even think of removing this answer. I find it generally useful (although it won't help in this particular question); people - searching for help - might find what you said and be really thankful.